# "No subscript members" error (Migrating to Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3

Im currently migrating my code to Swift 3, and am coming across an error that I cannot figure out. The observeValue(forKeyPath function has been updated in Swift 3, and my code no longer works b/c of this. The error states "Type '[NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?' has no subscript members", and its pointed to the subscripting of the constant "change".  Some reason in Swift 3, it won't let me subscript the change parameter.  How do I fix this error?

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    //Line below is generating error: Type '[NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?' has no subscript members
    let change = change["new"] as? Float
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `change` parameter is an optional, so you have to unwrap it before you can subscript it.  You should also use the enumeration value as the subscript instead of a raw string:

```
let change = change?[.newKey] as? Float
```

Comment: And given all of the optionals, it should be an `if let`.